# InfoPath 2010: Capture a submit success/failure

Tags: infopath

Just wondering if it's possible to catch a submit to SharePoint list success/failure.  I have a situation where we're inserting into a database as an action that follows a SharePoint submit, and if the submit fails (for valid reasons), I'd like to capture that to not run the actions afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has always been a pain point with submits and custom rules that they don't have error states associated with data connections. If you can uniquely identify the list item you are submitting based on column values, I would query the list immediately after the submit as a separate receive data connection, then put a conditional rule to check if the row was returned, and flag it to not run any remaining rules.

The other alternative (and the one that I have used the most in the past when  I have complex submit logic) is to write a custom web service.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think I'm gonna go down the web service route.

Comment: Chris, but how can query the list immediately if no other rules are executed in case submit failed?